# PHP- Get each value of an associative array in a foreach loop, then apply a function and echo the result

Tags: php

I have a piece of code similar to below:

```
    $list_links = array(
        [0] => Array // Here I get this error message Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'
            (
                "http://test.com/1/",
                "http://test.com/2/"
            ),
        [1] => Array
            (
                "http://test.com/3/",
                "http://test.com/4/"
            )
            );
    //Code stops to execute here        
    foreach($list_links as $link) {
        DoWork($link, $db_connect);
        if ($list_links[0]) {
            echo "this URL is from the 0 list";
        } else if ($list_links[1]) {
            echo "this URL is from the 1 list";
        }
    }
    //DoWork function works well and is already tested 
        function DoWork($link, $db_connect){
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
```

The problem is that the code stops to execute the `DoWork()` function when it reaches the `foreach()` loop because it can not get each URL from the list. 
Below are my questions:
1. Could you please see if `foreach($list_links as $link)` syntax is correct?
2. Are the `if` formats of `if ($list_links[0])` and `if ($list_links[1])` correct to echo the messages?

Comment: what do you mean by `if($list_links[0])` ?

Comment: If you wish to send those links in your array to the function then the syntax is wrong. You are sending the first child and not the 2nd level child, that is the actual link.

Comment: `foreach($list_links as $link)` — The syntax is alright, but it is logically incorrect. `$link` is not a link, but an array that contains two links. Either access the specific index inside the loop or use a nested foreach: `foreach($list_links as $sub) { foreach ($sub as $link) { ... } }`

Comment: @Amir, I don't mean anything :), I just want to check if the URL is selected from [0] list or [1] list,

Comment: I understand your goal, but remember, the `foreach` loop makes a copy of the array you send to it (Lerdorf. *PHP Programming: 2nd Edition*, Ch. 6, p. 129). Thus `$list_links[0]` (which points to an array, by the way), is not checking the actual array that `foreach` is working with. What you need to do is make a comparison (`in_array()`), not just test that an array is set, not empty, or not equal to false (which is all `if($list_links[0])` does ). The second array is `$list_links[1]` by the way. You need to think in terms of multiple dimensions to test if a link is in one of your arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, `foreach($list_links as $link)`, `$link` is not the URL, it is an array of URLs. Try a nested foreach instead:

```
foreach ($list_link as $link_array) {
    foreach ($link_array as $link) {
        DoWork($link, $db_connect);
    }
}
```

This will solve the first part of your problem. However, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with `if($list_links[0]) ...` . This just checks if `$list_links[0]` is true or false, essentially.

Further, regardless of what you're trying to do, it doesn't seem like much of an error check, because, given your data, each URL will always be apart of either `$list_link[0]` or `$list_link[1]`. If you want to simply state from which list each URL comes from, try this:

```
foreach ($list_link as $key=>$link_array) {
    foreach ($link_array as $link) {
        DoWork($link, $db_connect);
        echo 'this url is from the '.$key.' list';
    }
}
```

In regard to `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'`:

Remove the brackets from the keys. When declaring an array, they are not used.

```
$list_links = array(
    0 => array
        (
            "http://test.com/1/",
            "http://test.com/2/"
        ),
    1 => array
        (
            "http://test.com/3/",
            "http://test.com/4/"
        )
);
```

Note that if the key to an array element is a string, you must wrap it in quotes:

```
$array = array ('key' => 'value')
```

Further note that the default keys for an array are integers starting from 0, so in your case, you could simply remove the keys altogether to get the same result:

```
$list_links = array(
    array("http://test.com/1/", "http://test.com/2/"),
    array("http://test.com/3/", "http://test.com/4/")
);
```

This will automatically assign these two elements the keys 0 and 1, without the need to explicitly declare such. [**See a demo**](http://codepad.org/eyUQuZRw).

Comment: thanks Mark for your answer, I'm trying to solve this error and then test your code. `syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' on line 2` next to `[0] =>`, any idea?

Comment: @Apiah The problem is that when declaring an array, you don't wrap the keys in `[]`. Remove the brackets altogether - that will fix the error. Simply: `$list_link = array(0 => array( ... ), 1 => array( ...) ...`. If the keys were strings, you would need to wrap them in quotes, but in your case this is not needed. I will update my answer  with this information.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't suggest doing a DB call within a loop like this, but to answer your question:

Assign a `variable` to the function result

```
$list_links = DoWork($link, $db_connect);
if ($list_links[0]) {
    echo "this URL is from the 0 list";
 } else if ($list_links[2]) {
    echo "this URL is from the 1 list";
 }
```

Syntax error

```
$list_links = array(
        [0] => Array
            (
                "http://test.com/1/",
                "http://test.com/2/", <---- remove this ,
            ),
        [1] => Array
            (
                "http://test.com/3/",
                "http://test.com/4/",  <---- remove this ,
            )
            );
```

Comment: thank you Vector for your answer, I got this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in...`, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: that means you are not returning an array from `DoWork($link, $db_connect)`. If you are only passing a number value from `DoWork($link, $db_connect)` Then you can just use `if ($list_links){`

Comment: sorry for my miscommunication. PHP says the mentioned error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in line 2` which is next to `([0]=>` list,

Comment: You have a syntax error in your question, you have a `,` when you don't need one. see my answer.

Comment: I corrected the syntax but still am getting the same error message,

Comment: You say it is on line 2 `([0]=> list` but i do not see that in your example?

Comment: could you please check the question again, I added the error message,

Comment: OK, I get it now. What is within the `DoWork()` function. I can then recommend the correct referenced within the `if` statement

Comment: The trailing comma is not a syntax error. It's unusual, but valid. See http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php

Answer (score 2):

It could be this:

```
foreach($list_links as $link) {
    DoWork($link, $db_connect);
    if (in_array($links, $link_list[0])) {
        echo "this URL is from the 0 list";
    } elseif (in_array($links, $link_list[1])) {
        echo "this URL is from the 1 list";
    }
}
```

Notice that I use the recursive features of in_array() to check to see if the $links array has values in the 'zero' array `$link_list[0]`, or the 'one' array `$link_list[1]`.

[PHP Manual: in_array()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)